# Good practice for working with files in ASP.NET web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm new working with files so i have done some reading, altough i feel that i'm still not certain how to deal with them using asp.net web api. 
What i want is to be able to reach images thru my web api. What i've read so far is that many people prefer saving the file and then call for its URI, instead of saving the image to the database u only save the URI there. So I then created a imageController on the web api that does exactly this(Atleast working using localhost). I now get some people arguing that i should use blob storage(since i use Azure).

My question is: Is it wrong or bad practice to have a folder in my project where i save my image files? Else what would be the better way to save images?

Comment: In my private opinion, as you are using WEB, you should directly access all images using URL. Web is a technology which lets everybody effectively work with stored files. Why should you write a logic for working with static files while the web-server (e.g, IIS) is already doing this for you. It can be configured to work with MIME types, it can cache images for you. Moreover, browser can cache static images and prevent unnecessary traffic. However, this question is primarily opinion-based and I am suggesting to close it.

Comment: So having a folder in the project and saving images there is not wrong/bad practice?

Comment: IMHO, it is a bad practice! Considering you have cheap and highly available blob storage available in Azure, you should go with blob storage. I will provide a detailed answer a little bit later (if somebody hasn't answered it already by that time :)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really two questions:

### 1. database vs. filesystem

It depends on 2 main factors: security and performance.

If your images are sensitive and the risk of accessing them "outside" your app (for example by hotlinking) is unacceptable, you must go for database, and serving images via ASP.NET request - which you can authenticate any way you want. However, this is MUCH more resources-intensive than second option (see below).

If security is no concern, you definitely want to go for filesystem storage. On traditional hosting, you would save them "anywhere" on disk, and the IIS (the webserver) would serve them to user (by direct URL, bypassing your ASP.NET application). This alone is HUGE performance improvement over DB+ASP.NET solution for many reasons (request thread pool, memory pressure, avg. request duration, caching on IIS...).

### 2. Local directory on webrole vs. blob storage

However, in Azure you can, and HAVE TO go one step further - use dedicated blob storage, independent from your web role, so not even your IIS on webrole will be serving them, but dedicated server on blob storage (this does not need to concern you at all - it just works). Your web role should not store anything permanently - it can fail, be destroyed and replaced with new one at any time by Azure fabric. All permanent stuff must go to Azure blob storage.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @rouen's excellent answer (and I will focus only on local directory v/s blob storage).

Assuming you're deploying your WebApi as an Azure Web Application (instead of Web Role), consider the following scenarios:

- What would happen to your images if accidentally you delete your Web Application. In that case, all your images will be lost.
- What would happen if you need to scale your application from one instances to more than one. Since the files are located in instances local directory, they will not be replicated across other instances. If a request to fetch the image lands on an instance where the image is not present on the VM, then you will not be able to serve that image.
- What would happen if you need to store more images than the disk size available to you in your web application?
- What would happen if you need to serve the same images through another application (other than your WebApi)?

Considering all these, my recommendation would be to go with blob storage. What you do is store the image in blob storage and save the image URL in the database. Some of the advantages offered by blob storage are:

- At this time, you can store 500 GB worth of data in a single blob storage account. If you need more space, you simply create another storage account. Currently you can create 100 storage accounts per subscription so essentially you can store 50TB worth of data in a single subscription.
- Blob storage is cheap and you only pay for the storage that you use + storage transaction costs which are also very cheap.
- Contents in blob storage are replicated thrice and if you opt for geo-redundancy option (there's an extra cost for that), your content is replicated six time (three times in primary region + three times in secondary region). However you should not [confuse replication with backup](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/cloud-storage-replication-is-not-backup/)!
- Since the content is served from blob storage, you're essentially freeing up IIS server from serving that content.
- You can take advantage of Azure CDN and serve the content from a CDN node closest to your end user.

Considering all these advantages, I would strongly urge you to take a look at blob storage.

Comment: Thanks, you know about any documentation/clip/code where they show how to implement working with azure blobs within a asp.net web api? Just got to have this clarified, i can use my asp.net web application for this right? the examples i see invovles creating a console application #Imtotalbeginner

Comment: Yes, you can use asp.net web application. There's a .Net Storage Client library on Nuget (http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) that you will use in your application to communicate with Azure Storage. The mechanism remains the same as you would do through console application.

Comment: Nice thing about Azure is you can use the parts independently. Blob storage is storage - you can use it for whatever you want. I am using it to backup my photos for example (without anything else deployed on azure on this account :) If I wish, I can write a console app to access this photos and do something, then write webapp to present them, then write mobile app to manage them, whatever :) Same with azure SQL databases, other types of storage, caches...

Comment: I've managed to create blob storages now and upload and get files from it. you guys seem to know one and another but this so i figured if maybe u guys knew if there was a way to make sure the blob names are unique?

Comment: Without looking at your code, it would be hard to guess but when you create a reference for `CloudBlockBlob`, simply use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString().<extension e.g. png/gif>` for the blob name. For example, `blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png");`. HTH.